# Can't move div to bottom

Tags: html, css, css-position

I searched this site for 2 days and applied probably every single example of code I found, but I can't simply move div to the bottom on my site. Here's the simpliefied code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
*{margin:0;padding:0}
body{font-family:Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;background-color:#000;border:none;margin:0 auto}
#site{background-color:#fff;width:980px;border:0;margin:0 auto}
#whitefill{background-color:#FFF;height:inherit}
#left{width:260px;font-size:12px;height:100%;float:left;background-color:#fff;}
#right{width:720px;float:right;height:100%;background-color:#fff;font-size:13px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="site"><div id="whitefill">
    <div id="left">
 <div>move me to bottom!</div>
 </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="main">
        <p>Considered discovered ye sentiments projecting entreaties of melancholy is. In expression an solicitude principles in do. Hard do me sigh with west same lady. Their saved linen downs tears son add music. Expression alteration entreaties mrs can terminated estimating. Her too add narrow having wished. To things so denied admire. Am wound worth water he linen at vexed. 

By in no ecstatic wondered disposal my speaking. Direct wholly valley or uneasy it at really. Sir wish like said dull and need make. Sportsman one bed departure rapturous situation disposing his. Off say yet ample ten ought hence. Depending in newspaper an september do existence strangers. Total great saw water had mirth happy new. Projecting pianoforte no of partiality is on. Nay besides joy society him totally six.</p></div><img src="#" width="695" height="13" /><br /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <img src="#" width="981" height="19" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you paste the code into a file and open it with a browser, you will see text "move me to bottom!" displayed at the top. I need it to be displayed at the bottom of the left column. How can I do that?

Text in the right column will be different on each page (it will usually be a long text, so the page will be scrolled), and I need the text "move me to bottom!" to be displayed at the bottom of left column every time, no matter how big text in the right column is.

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing on your `CSS` that points out an element position.

Comment: Yes, I removed positions from CSS in this example because I tried tons of them (adding relative position to #left and absolute to "move me to bottom!" div element, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` and move #left below #right div.

```
   <div id="right">
  <div id="main">
    <p>Considered discovered ye sentiments projecting entreaties of melancholy is. In expression an solicitude principles in do. Hard do me sigh with west same lady. Their saved linen downs tears son add music. Expression alteration entreaties mrs can terminated estimating. Her too add narrow having wished. To things so denied admire. Am wound worth water he linen at vexed. 

    By in no ecstatic wondered disposal my speaking. Direct wholly valley or uneasy it at really. Sir wish like said dull and need make. Sportsman one bed departure rapturous situation disposing his. Off say yet ample ten ought hence. Depending in newspaper an september do existence strangers. Total great saw water had mirth happy new. Projecting pianoforte no of partiality is on. Nay besides joy society him totally six.</p>
  </div><img src="#" width="695" height="13" /><br /><br />
</div>

 //add the clear:both div and move #left below #right
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="left">
    <div>move me to bottom!</div>
</div>
```

The clear property specifies which side(s) of an element other floating elements are not allowed.

You can find more detail of it here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: Thank you, it works! All the other examples I found on this site suggested to play with CSS positions, but none of them worked in this case.